# KDE logoff broke, how do I fix it?

Tags: kde4

My 'logoff' button stopped working on KDE. I've googled tons, and none of the solutions are working.

If I don't use the official logoff mechanism, on restart, my desktop session state is lost

I can create a new user, and it works for the new user,  so I've I've removed my `~/.kde`  folder, rebuilt my desktop configuration settings (>=4 hrs to do), and at some point the  problem has, somehow spontaneously returned.  I have a 14.04 LTS install.

Answer (score 1):

I ran:

```
rm ~/.kde/share/config/ksmserverrc 
sudo reboot now
```

on reboot, was able to log off again

Thanks to [this post on Kubuntu Forums](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?61623-How-I-got-this-fixed-gt-KDE-cannot-logout-shutdown-reboot-etc)